# next-auth error (try signing different account) when deploying on Firebase

Tags: firebase, authentication, next.js, google-oauth, next-auth

I got stuck with this issue for so long. To find the root cause, I tested the Next-auth authentication by running [next-auth example code](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth-example). Everything runed just fine on local (http://localhost:3000) but when deploying to Firebase, it stopped working. Both Github and Google authentication failed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqbkU.png)

---

The full log is as follows,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiLzU.png)

---

### .env.local is as follows,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTCvc.png)

### [...NextAuth].ts is as follows (almost same as in the repo)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWWqs.png)

Callback link has been added to Google Credential as well as github.

It worked on local so callback link, GOOGLE_ID, and GOOGLE_SECRET should be correct.

Comment: Same here, did you solved it?

Comment: Same here too, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the issuer value is correct. It helped me to solve the "try signing different account" error

```
providers: [
          KeycloakProvider({
            clientId: process.env.NEXTAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
            issuer: process.env.NEXTAUTH_CLIENT_ISSUER,
          }),
        ],
```

This issuer should be realm Url.
Eg:NEXTAUTH_CLIENT_ISSUER=http://localhost:8090/auth/realms/Test

Comment: where is issuer value located?

Answer (score 1):

I turn off my vpn and it works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: what is the explanation behind this? Why after turning off the vpn it started to work?

Comment: the vpn is not turned on. i am just connected to android hotspot instead of my wifi. what now?

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead and check your .env file and confirm whether your provider names are okay.

Comment: they are correct. what now?

Answer (score 0):

check spelling of your client id and secret  --this worked for and try to keep .env file on global app folder ex:my-app

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.
I solved it by going to my .env.local
I had an error on my "GOOGLE_ID_SECRET"

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that my problem was that i forgot to install the prisma client, try doing :
npm i @prisma/client

Answer (score 0):

[According to this](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/3186) :

Go to `next-auth/src/core/lib/oauth/client.ts` inside your `node_modules`, and set
`client[custom.clock_tolerance]` to a value greater than 10, maybe 100.

You can find it in line 45.

(worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

It is a configuration issue.....Kindly put your  google id and secret into this file found in your root directly of your nextJS project next.config.js

worked for me

```
module.exports = {
    env: {
        apiUrl: 'https://powerlightng.com',
        GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID : "xxxxxx",
       GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET: "xxxxxxxxx"
    },
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue but I was using Supabase with Google provider. All the setup was okay. Sometimes sign in with Google would work and others it would show that error. I simply added async await to the signIn function.

```
<button
    onClick={async() => {
      await signIn();
    }}
  >
    Sign in
  </button>
```

Comment: doesn't work. now what?